# Phaser game library with javascript and VS 2013 web express

Tags: asp.net-mvc, phaser-framework

So I'm totally new to the Phaser game library and I'm trying to setup a project using VS 2013 web express in a MVC project. I'm wanting to use javascript (not typescript) and I'm assuming I can just use the IISExpress web service that VS creates when it starts. Most of the tutorials I've seen talk about getting apache setup, but I'd prefer to just use IISExpress when I click run from VS as it's just easier because I don't have to do anything.

So I added phaser to my project. It complained about pixi. So I added pixi to my project, and when I have the following line I get the following error:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(500, 600, Phaser.AUTO, 'game_div');

"JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this action"
```

Is my setup of Phaser OK? Can I not use IISExpress from VS to run phaser?

My Index.cshtml is

```
@section scripts{
<script src="~/Scripts/pixi/Pixi.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/phaser/src/Phaser.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/main.js"></script>
}

<div id="game_div">

</div>
```